Select line on gutter click in IntelliJ IDEA 2024
I discovered that in IntelliJ IDEA 2024 (e.g. 2024.2.4), lines are no longer selected on gutter clicks.
Is there some checkbox I have to (un)check in the settings?

Turn off "Breakpoints over line numbers". To do so, press Shift+Shift, type "Breakpoints over line numbers" and toggle switch to "off".
